# Session control with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I set the sessiontimeout property to 15 minutes, I want to redirect after 15 minutes. For this, I made my redirect inside the session_end, but it does not do the redirect on the client side. I thought of writing a JavaScript function and sending a request to a Controller that checks the session every 1 minute and redirecting it. Do you think this method makes sense? What would you suggest as an alternative?

And I also tried writing a filter :

```
 public class SessionTimeout : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;

            if (session["UsersDetails"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Login/Login");
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use SignalR if you want to notify the client from the server side that  the session timeout, but in general you redirect the client when he tries a new request even if the client session passed the 15 mins.

Comment: Thank you. So, by what methods can this be done without using SignalR? I'm just asking to learn, to improve myself.

Comment: Redirect only works in response to a Request. At Session_End the browser may long be shut down (and Session_End is not guaranteed to fire)

Comment: Alternative is a client-side (javascript) timeout redirecting to the logout page in 15 minutes